# Map container is already initialized

Tags: leaflet, javascript, typescript, angular2, angular

In Leaflet, I want all my markers to be hidden at the same time and show on the click of a checkbox.

Here is my code:

```
var cordnt=this.coordinates;
var overlayMarker = {};
 console.log("testing coodinates", cordnt)
var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map)
for (i = 0; i < cordnt.length; i++) {
  newMarker = new L.marker([cordnt[i][0], cordnt[i][1]]).bindPopup(notation.desc);
  newMarker.openPopup()
   layerGroup.addLayer([newMarker])
  Object.assign(overlayMarker, {'Markers': layerGroup});
}

console.log("testing latlong",layerGroup)
L.control.layers(null, overlayMarker).addTo(map);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to GSE ! I've reformated your question and your code, and add a clear question. Please edit your post for add details, code with comments, leaflet version and which navigator used, etc.

Comment: The title of a question should not be the only non-code. In fact, the title should be brief summary of what the question is about, no more. The body requires details of the versions of software, the purpose, the data, and the problem encountered. "Wall of code" posts are downvoted and closed.

Comment: Can you explain meaning of the title "Map container is already initialized"? It sounds like an error message. At which step it appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to read a file and create markers, and these markers should be in a layergroup so Leaflet handles them as one layer. Here is something similar to your code that I used.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var lng = data[i].coordinates[0];
        var lat = data[i].coordinates[1];
        var Line1 = data[i].addressLine1;
        var Line2 = data[i].addressLine2;
        MCDs = L.marker([lat,lng]).bindPopup("<b>Address: </b>" + Line1 + "<br />Region: " + Line2);
        mcd.addLayer(MCDs);
    } 
});

//mcd.addTo(map);  //uncomment if you want to layergroup drawn when the map draws, //leave commented if you want it unchecked in the layer control.

var overlayMaps = {
    "JSON Layer Group":mcd 
};  

//Add layer control
var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thank you Bill i really appreciate your help thanks a lot